# List all property indices in agens-graph

Tags: agens-graph

I am evaluating Agensgraph v1.2 for usage in my company. I am trying to use normal postgres shell commands in agens shell to get information about the indices, tables etc. I am not able to list indices with \di command.

Is there a way to list all the property indices that are currently in the db?

It will also be helpful if I can get a link to some documentation of the system tables used by Agensgraph, which I can query if the shell commands are not yet fully functional for the graph side.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to list the indices using the describe graph vertices command (\dGv).